# Factor intercorrelations and model design

Tags: correlation, modeling, factor-analysis, covariance

Having done an exploratory factor analysis (SPSS), what exactly can I infer from the factor intercorrelation table that is output after the factors are extracted/rotated?

If two factors are relatively highly correlated (let's say the .4-.6 range or higher), does this mean that when constructing my model graphically, I could put a bidirectional line between the two latent variables representing the factors?

Is that the sort of thing the intercorrelation table represents?  If not, what part of the output/what further analysis are you supposed to use to justify putting those bi- or unidireectional lines between factors?

I am a newbie on a deadline so help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

First, since your factors are correlated you must have used an oblique rotation. Why did you do this? The usual reason (and the only one I can think of offhand) is that you suspect your factors will be correlated.

Second, correlations between factors just means that the factors are correlated. I don't know what your bidirectional line would mean. Are you talking about a path diagram? Did you have a path model that you were testing? Were there bidirectional lines in that model? Perhaps not, since you are doing exploratory analysis. If you are using a bidirectional line to represent correlation then, yes, you can put such a line. But you can put such lines between **all** the factors, since they will all be correlated, even if some correlations are weak and others strong. You can label the line with the correlation.

Third, please tell us what your model is, what your variables are, what type of factor analysis and rotation you used, what your research questions are and so on. You may find this post from my blog helpful: [How to ask a statistics question.](http://www.statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/how-to-ask-a-statistics-question/)  That will let us give more specific help.